Anaconda stuck at setting up package cache
When I tried to install Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Windows-x86_64, it got stuck at the "setting up package cache" stage. It took almost 1-2 hours to get past this step, which is a lot longer than the 10 minutes others mentioned. In my opinion, if you know your system is still working, don’t stop it; just let it run. It’s likely that the process took longer because you checked the "Clear the package cache upon completion" option!
You can also try turning off your antivirus, which might help resolve the issue.

This question is similar to: Anaconda Installation stuck at - 'Setting up the package cache'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is your question?
